# Will elementary support a path to upgrade between releases?

Tags: updates, kernel

I couldn't find information regarding this in the official web-page.

I can't use elementaryOS professionally if I am required to reinstall the system at each release, there are far too much specialized software that I would have to reinstall.

- When (if ever) will elementaryOS offer an upgrade path for its users?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1486694

Comment: There is no info on what they will do in the future. On the other side,  for most Linux systems and especially Ubuntu-based ones, full install is recommended, especially from users' side, and my own experience confirms that.  The risks involved by upgrading between releases are at least as big as the downsides of reinstalling programs. Have you often used upgrades between releases?

Comment: @cipricus This is a misinformed statement. Full installs are not in any way the recommended way of keeping a install tidy. This became something because of Linux Mint and because is comfortable to the elementaryOS devs. But think of Arch based distros, they are tidier and faster than debian based, no conf files are removed over the upgrades. The user have to take care of this. This is an important issue for elementary if they plan to be a major player.

Comment: @if_araujo ~ `misinformed`: I think you are referring to `for most Linux systems and especially Ubuntu-based ones, full install is recommended`. Maybe an overstatement `most Linux`, but as far as Ubuntu-based are concerned I am talking from my own experience, and you also confirm the idea in relation to Mint and elementary OS , which both are amongst prominent distros on distrowhatch and already major players no matter what the Arch fans may like to think

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no upgrade path between elementary versions. I am not aware of any plans to implement that either.

Comment: what about this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/16483/170

Comment: That will work but it's a workaround and not technically an upgrade path and requires the users to have already created partitions for /home and also all other locations where applications were installed. Bottomline: not a reasonable method for most users.